# Swift: I want to read a list of countries with many attributes from a csv files and use this for my app. How can I implement this?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, core-data, swift4

I am developing an iOS app using Swift (still new to swift).

I have a databank saved as a csv file and that is primarily the core of the app. The databank contains a table divided into a list of all countries (rows) each with many attributes/descriptors (the columns). Really there is no relationship between the countries.

What I would like to do is to be able to display this information for the (selected) country in my app. As well as do other things like search/filtering/sorting based on the attribute/property chosen.

The databank might be updated in the future with the release of app updates but other than that I think I want it to be read once from the csv file and then the app uses that data.

Am I right in thinking that the best way to implement this is by using Core Data with ONE entity (country) with the different attributes? So then all I have to do is read the csv file once and persistent store all the data and use it from there.

Or is Core Data not the best implementation? Shall I just create a class Country with the many attributes and use that? But then that means the app will have to read the csv every time it opens and save the data to arrays etc if I wanted to filter or sort?

So I guess in summary my questions are:
1. Use Core Data or not? If not then what do you think the best implementation is?
2. If using Core Data, am I just creating ONE entity (so no relationships etc).

Comment: I guess there is no 'right' or 'wrong' answer to this. You can use CoreData for sure (and get for free a lot of functionality like synchronized `UITableView`s etc). If you decide to go with it, [here is](https://www.objc.io/issues/4-core-data/importing-large-data-sets-into-core-data/) an excellent article by objc.io on dataset importing

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Would you say my database would then include ONE entity which is the country and everything else falls as attributes for the entity Country?

Answer (score 0):

What would see this as is that you would want to load this into your database of choice; Thus **CoreData** or **SQLite** or even **Realm** would work.

In case you don't have the data available for any of them yet and you want to load them in using swift this is a parser that I wrote for a similar situation where CSV is my raw datasource that I need to parse:

```
if let listFile = try? String(contentsOfFile: path) {
                let lines = listFile.components(separatedBy: "\n")

                // NOTE: There is also a CSV format that uses ',' as a separator
                // So verify if yours uses ';' or ','
                let rows: [[String: String]] = lines.flatMap() {
                    (item) -> [String: String]? in
                    let components = item.components(separatedBy: ";")
                    if components.count != 3 {
                        return nil
                    }
                    // Modify this part to parse the X amount of columns
                    // you have in your countries.csv
                    let dict = [
                        "identity":    components[0],
                        "description": components[1].lowercased(),
                        "points":      components[2]
                    ]
                    return dict
                }
            }

}
```

Then after you have the data in an `[[String: String]]` format you could parse that row by row and insert them into the database you chose to use.

I believe in **Swift4** it should be possible to use the new `Codable` protocols in order to achieve a result that would look a lot cleaner; but I have not written an Encoder/Decoder for CSV files ( yet ) that would allow you to do this. If there is one available I'll post it here.

There is also a CSV parser available on github here:
[SwiftCSV](https://github.com/naoty/SwiftCSV)
I have never used it, but who knows; might be helpful to you.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Would you say my database would then include ONE entity which is the country and everything else falls as attributes for the entity Country?

Comment: @A.Zada your database should have the country name as its primary field ( I forgot the terminology in CoreData, but the functionality is there ) so you can quickly look it up and or perform querios on it. The rest of the data of said country should be attributes of the item. The point of transferring the CSV file to a database is for efficient access to the data you need. Parsing 200+ lines of text every time you need some specific information is wasteful at best.